# R plotly hover information is not showing

Tags: r

when using the code below and selecting just one row no hover info is provided. The hover text argument is used to display additional information about each property when the user hovers over the corresponding marker, such as the number of rooms, price, and square meter value. The custom data argument, customdata, is used to store links to external pages that provide more information about each property, and custom JavaScript code is added to open these links in a new window when the user clicks on a marker. The issue is that the hover info is not displayed for just one row in the plot.

```
library(plotly) # https://plotly.com/r/mapbox-layers

df <- data.frame(
  price = c(3000000, 5000000, 6000000),
  rooms = c("3+1", "4+1", "5+1"),
  m2 = c(80, 100, 160),
  location = c("Brno", "Brno", "Brno"),
  lat = c(49.18052, 49.20037, 49.20037),
  lon = c(16.67907, 16.60228, 16.60228),
  link = c("https://www.example.com/property/1", "https://www.example.com/property/2", "https://www.example.com/property/3")
)

price_min <- 3000000
price_max <- 3100000
m2_min <- 45
m2_max <- 125

test <- subset(df, price >= price_min & price <= price_max & m2 >= m2_min & m2 <= m2_max)

# Prepare data
plotly <- as.data.frame(subset(test, select = c("price", "rooms", "m2", "location", "lat", "lon", "link")))

plotly$hover_text <- paste("<br>",
                           "Type: ", plotly$rooms, "<br>",
                           "Price: ", plotly$price, " CZK", "<br>",
                           "M2: ", plotly$m2, " m2", "<br>",
                           "Location: ", plotly$location)


# Create plotly figure
fig <- plot_ly(
  data = plotly,
  lat = ~lat,
  lon = ~lon,
  marker = list(size = 7, color = "blue"),
  type = 'scattermapbox',
  hovertext = ~hover_text,
  customdata = ~link, # stores links as custom data
  hovertemplate = paste(# renders custom data (link)
    '<br><extra>%{hovertext}</extra>'), # includes hovertext
  mode = 'markers+text', # enables clicking on markers
  textposition = 'middle center', # centers text on markers
  textfont = list(color = 'black', size = 10) # sets font color and size of text
) %>%
  # Add custom JavaScript code to open link in new window when marker is clicked
  onRender("
            function(el) {
              el.on('plotly_click', function(d) {
                var url = d.points[0].customdata;
                window.open(url);
              });
            }")

# Customize layout
fig <- fig %>%
  layout(
    mapbox = list(
      style = 'open-street-map',
      zoom = 10,
      center = list(lon = 16.6068, lat = 49.1951)),
    margin = list(l = 0, r = 0, t = 0, b = 0))

# Display plotly figure
fig
```